# Fitting dose-response models in python (R drc library equivalent)

Tags: python, r, drc

I have been working with DRC library in R for quite a time. Now I would need a similar library to fit dose-response models in python, I've been googling with any discobering.

Does anyone know some python package to do that?

Many thanks!

Xevi